# A perplexing spacetime curve problem

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, gravity, spacetime, curvature

I was recently studying quantum physics and came across Einstein's definition of "GRAVITY as a curve in spacetime". Assuming that, it means that Earth bends the spacetime around it and if we put two objects inside earth we know that they have an attraction in between.

So my question is, "How is it possible for a spacetime curve to exist inside the Earth (to produce gravity between objects) if all of it was bent by the huge mass of Earth?".

In my opinion, **either Einstein's hypothesis is false or Newton was wrong that there is attraction between 2 objects.**

(Pardon me, if you find that I lack any particular information)

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. Please try to make your question about a precise, clearly stated problem. The apparent contradiction you raise in terms natural language is not precise enough to be validated our refuted. If you formulate Newton's and Einstein's theory of gravity precisely, you can show how their predictions agree in the limit of low mass densities and speeds small compared to the speed of light.

Comment: (Note: You should also clarify how does quantum physics come into play in relation to your question or remove the reference from the question).

Answer (score 1):

> either Einstein's hypothesis is false or Newton was wrong that there is attraction between 2 objects.

As you continue studying General Relativity, you should soon see that the physics community has long ago come to terms with the idea that General Relativity is a reinterpretation of gravity that **replaces** Newton's picture.

Newton's simplified picture of gravity, however, is sufficient for almost all purposes.